# 502 bad gateway error after installing WordPress and MySQL database on azure container instance in a virtual network

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-container-instances

Following ARM template successfully deployed WordPress and MySQL database on the azure container instance in a virtual network but I'm facing 502 bad gateway error while updating WordPress. Also I'm get link expired when uploading theme of 30MB size.

**azuredeploy.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "vnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "aci-vnet",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "VNet name"
      }
    },
    "vnetAddressPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.0.0/16",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Address prefix"
      }
    },
    "subnet1AddressPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.0.0/24",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Subnet prefix for ACI"
      }
    },
    "subnet1Name": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "aci-subnet",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Subnet name for ACI"
      }
    },
    "subnet2AddressPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.1.0/24",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Subnet prefix for application gateway"
      }
    },
    "subnet2Name": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "ag-subnet",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Subnet name for application gateway"
      }
    },
    "mysqlPassword": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "MySQL database password"
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "storageAccountName": "[uniquestring(resourceGroup().id)]",
    "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS",
    "publicIPAddressName": "publicIp1",
    "publicIPRef": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',variables('publicIPAddressName'))]",
    "networkProfileName": "aci-networkProfile",
    "interfaceConfigName": "eth0",
    "interfaceIpConfig": "ipconfigprofile1",
    "image": "microsoft/azure-cli",
    "shareContainerGroupName": "createshare-containerinstance",
    "wordpressContainerGroupName": "wordpress-containerinstance",
    "mysqlContainerGroupName": "mysql-containerinstance",
    "wordpressShareName": "wordpress-share",
    "mysqlShareName": "mysql-share",
    "cpuCores": "1.0",
    "memoryInGb": "1.5",
    "skuName": "Standard_Medium",
    "capacity": "2",
    "applicationGatewayName": "applicationGateway1",
    "subnet2Ref": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('vnetName'), parameters('subnet2Name'))]",
    "wordpressContainerGroupRef": "[resourceId('Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/', variables('wordpresscontainerGroupName'))]",
    "mysqlContainerGroupRef": "[resourceId('Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/', variables('mysqlContainerGroupName'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[variables('storageAccountType')]"
      },
      "kind": "Storage",
      "properties": {}
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "name": "[variables('publicIPAddressName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
        "dnsSettings": {
          "domainNameLabel": "[concat('acisite', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "name": "[parameters('vnetName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[parameters('vnetAddressPrefix')]"
          ]
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "[parameters('subnet1Name')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnet1AddressPrefix')]",
              "serviceEndpoints": [
                {
                  "service": "Microsoft.Storage",
                  "locations": [
                    "[parameters('location')]"
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "delegations": [
                {
                  "name": "DelegationService",
                  "properties": {
                    "serviceName": "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "[parameters('subnet2Name')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnet2AddressPrefix')]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[variables('networkProfileName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkProfiles",
      "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('vnetName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "containerNetworkInterfaceConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "[variables('interfaceConfigName')]",
            "properties": {
              "ipConfigurations": [
                {
                  "name": "[variables('interfaceIpConfig')]",
                  "properties": {
                    "subnet": {
                      "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('vnetName'), parameters('subnet1Name'))]"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[variables('shareContainerGroupName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2019-12-01",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('storageAccountName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "[variables('wordpressShareName')]",
            "properties": {
              "image": "[variables('image')]",
              "command": [
                "az",
                "storage",
                "share",
                "create",
                "--name",
                "[variables('wordpressShareName')]"
              ],
              "environmentVariables": [
                {
                  "name": "AZURE_STORAGE_KEY",
                  "value": "[listKeys(variables('storageAccountName'),'2017-10-01').keys[0].value]"
                },
                {
                  "name": "AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT",
                  "value": "[variables('storageAccountName')]"
                }
              ],
              "resources": {
                "requests": {
                  "cpu": "[variables('cpuCores')]",
                  "memoryInGb": "[variables('memoryInGb')]"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "[variables('mysqlShareName')]",
            "properties": {
              "image": "[variables('image')]",
              "command": [
                "az",
                "storage",
                "share",
                "create",
                "--name",
                "[variables('mysqlShareName')]"
              ],
              "environmentVariables": [
                {
                  "name": "AZURE_STORAGE_KEY",
                  "value": "[listKeys(variables('storageAccountName'),'2017-10-01').keys[0].value]"
                },
                {
                  "name": "AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT",
                  "value": "[variables('storageAccountName')]"
                }
              ],
              "resources": {
                "requests": {
                  "cpu": "[variables('cpuCores')]",
                  "memoryInGb": "[variables('memoryInGb')]"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "OnFailure",
        "osType": "Linux"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[variables('mysqlContainerGroupName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2019-12-01",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/', variables('shareContainerGroupName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkProfiles/', variables('networkProfileName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "mysql",
            "properties": {
              "image": "mysql:5.6",
              "ports": [
                {
                  "protocol": "Tcp",
                  "port": 3306
                }
              ],
              "environmentVariables": [
                {
                  "name": "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD",
                  "value": "[parameters('mysqlPassword')]"
                }
              ],
              "volumeMounts": [
                {
                  "mountPath": "/var/lib/mysql",
                  "name": "mysqlfile"
                }
              ],
              "resources": {
                "requests": {
                  "cpu": "[variables('cpuCores')]",
                  "memoryInGb": "[variables('memoryInGb')]"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "volumes": [
          {
            "azureFile": {
              "shareName": "[variables('mysqlShareName')]",
              "storageAccountKey": "[listKeys(variables('storageAccountName'),'2017-10-01').keys[0].value]",
              "storageAccountName": "[variables('storageAccountName')]"
            },
            "name": "mysqlfile"
          }
        ],
        "networkProfile": {
          "Id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkProfiles', variables('networkProfileName'))]"
        },
        "osType": "Linux"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[variables('wordpressContainerGroupName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2019-12-01",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/', variables('shareContainerGroupName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/', variables('mysqlContainerGroupName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "wordpress",
            "properties": {
              "image": "wordpress:4.9-apache",
              "ports": [
                {
                  "protocol": "Tcp",
                  "port": 80
                }
              ],
              "environmentVariables": [
                {
                  "name": "WORDPRESS_DB_HOST",
                  "value": "[concat(reference(variables('mysqlContainerGroupRef')).ipAddress.ip, ':3306')]"
                },
                {
                  "name": "WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD",
                  "value": "[parameters('mysqlPassword')]"
                }
              ],
              "volumeMounts": [
                {
                  "mountPath": "/var/www/html",
                  "name": "wordpressfile"
                }
              ],
              "resources": {
                "requests": {
                  "cpu": "[variables('cpuCores')]",
                  "memoryInGb": "[variables('memoryInGb')]"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "volumes": [
          {
            "azureFile": {
              "shareName": "[variables('wordpressShareName')]",
              "storageAccountKey": "[listKeys(variables('storageAccountName'),'2017-10-01').keys[0].value]",
              "storageAccountName": "[variables('storageAccountName')]"
            },
            "name": "wordpressfile"
          }
        ],
        "networkProfile": {
          "Id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkProfiles', variables('networkProfileName'))]"
        },
        "osType": "Linux"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
      "name": "[variables('applicationGatewayName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('vnetName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', variables('publicIPAddressName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/', variables('wordpressContainerGroupName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "sku": {
          "name": "[variables('skuName')]",
          "tier": "Standard",
          "capacity": "[variables('capacity')]"
        },
        "gatewayIPConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "appGatewayIpConfig",
            "properties": {
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('subnet2Ref')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "frontendIPConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "appGatewayFrontendIP",
            "properties": {
              "PublicIPAddress": {
                "id": "[variables('publicIPRef')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "frontendPorts": [
          {
            "name": "appGatewayFrontendPort",
            "properties": {
              "Port": 80
            }
          }
        ],
        "backendAddressPools": [
          {
            "name": "appGatewayBackendPool",
            "properties": {
              "BackendAddresses": [
                {
                  "IpAddress": "[reference(variables('wordpressContainerGroupRef')).ipAddress.ip]"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "backendHttpSettingsCollection": [
          {
            "name": "appGatewayBackendHttpSettings",
            "properties": {
              "Port": 80,
              "Protocol": "Http",
              "CookieBasedAffinity": "Disabled"
            }
          }
        ],
        "httpListeners": [
          {
            "name": "appGatewayHttpListener",
            "properties": {
              "FrontendIPConfiguration": {
                "Id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendIPConfigurations', variables('applicationGatewayName'), 'appGatewayFrontendIP')]"
              },
              "FrontendPort": {
                "Id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendPorts', variables('applicationGatewayName'), 'appGatewayFrontendPort')]"
              },
              "Protocol": "Http"
            }
          }
        ],
        "requestRoutingRules": [
          {
            "Name": "rule1",
            "properties": {
              "RuleType": "Basic",
              "httpListener": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/httpListeners', variables('applicationGatewayName'), 'appGatewayHttpListener')]"
              },
              "backendAddressPool": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/backendAddressPools', variables('applicationGatewayName'), 'appGatewayBackendPool')]"
              },
              "backendHttpSettings": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/backendHttpSettingsCollection', variables('applicationGatewayName'), 'appGatewayBackendHttpSettings')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "SiteFQDN": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(variables('publicIPRef')).dnsSettings.fqdn]"
    }
  }
}
```

**azuredeploy.parameters.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "mysqlPassword": {
      "value": "GEN-PASSWORD"
    }
  }
}
```

**Solution overview and deployed resources**

The following resources are deployed as part of the solution

- Azure Container Instance: Azure Container Instance to host the WordPress site.
- Azure Container Instance: Azure Container Instance to host the MySQL database.
- Azure Container Instance: A run-once Azure Container Instance, where the az-cli is executed to create the file shares
- Storage Account: Storage account for the file shares to store the WordPress site content and MySQL database.
- File share: Azure File shares to store WordPress site content and MySQL database.
  Application gateway: Application gateway for WordPress site. It exposes public network access to WordPress site in VNet.
- Virtual network: Virtual network for WordPress site, MySQL database, Application gateway.

**One click deploy to Azure**

[Click here](https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Template/uri/https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2FAzure%2Fazure-quickstart-templates%2Fmaster%2F201-aci-wordpress-vnet%2Fazuredeploy.json) to deploy to Azure

Comment: To update WordPress, go to WordPress Dashboard > Updates > Update now                 after updating 502 bad gateway error is  showing   unable to access wordpress